# get elements with class names that has a certain pattern in jquery joomla

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

I am using a Joomla CMS application. Apparently one of our developers is using Firefox and has a Skype click to call extension. Whenever he is changing the content, for some reason the skype click to call code goes with it. Since I cannot assist the developer into removing all the codes, I decided to use jquery to filter out all of the class names that has "skype" on it, but I do not know what code should I use.

here are some examples of those class names:

```
class="skype_c2c_logo_img"
class="skype_c2c_highlighting_inactive_common"
class="skype_c2c_container notranslate"
```

Is it possible for me to call all the elements with the classname "skype"?

This is what I intend to do for the content:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

????? // what code to call  
???.hide();

});
```

But I do not know what would be the code to get all the classes which contain the word "skype".

Comment: For all class attributes starting with "skype_" - `$('[class^=skype_]')`. For all class attributes containing "skype_" `$('[class*=skype_]')`

Comment: Do note that matching elements solely based on their class prefix requires evaluation of *all* elements in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("*[class*=skype_c2c]").hide();
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v3yvh/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

The class starts with `skype_`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("[class^='skype_']").hide();

});
```

The class that contains `skype_`

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $("[class*='skype_']").hide();

    });
```

Hope it works..

Answer (score 0):

you could use [starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$("[class^='skype_c2c_']").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me... 
I needed to ensure that I preserved the actual phone number..
(Oddly enough, it seems to not work consistently in IE 11.. but works great in all other browsers.)

```
    //REMOVE SKYPE ELEMS - This makes assumptions based on current skype elem classes
    function removeSkype() {
        try {
            var topSkypeElem = $(".skype_c2c_highlighting_inactive_common"); //find the topmost skype container
            var innerContentContainer = $('.skype_c2c_text_span');
            var innerContent = $(innerContentContainer).html(); //get phone number from existing skype elem
            var newSpan = $("<span></span>)"); //new elem to hold phone number
            $(newSpan).html(innerContent); //Create a new span with the phone number
            $(newSpan).insertBefore(topSkypeElem); //insert the phone number before the skype elems
            $(topSkypeElem).remove(); // remove the top skype elem
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    }
```